# Verifying a Loop Modifies Clause

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

Right, so I am trying to verify the following `fill()` method.  Currently the first and third `invariant` clauses fail, and I'm not entirely surely why.  Any thoughts appreciated!

```
class List {
    var data : int;
    var next : List?;
    ghost var rep : set<List>;

    constructor(d : int) 
    ensures this.valid();
    {
        this.data := d;
        this.next := null;
        this.rep := {this};
    }

    predicate valid() 
    reads this, rep;
    decreases rep + {this};
    {
        this in rep
        && (next != null ==> (
            next in rep
            && next.rep <= rep
            && this !in next.rep 
            && next.valid()            
        ))
    }
} 

method fill(ol : List, on : int) 
requires ol.valid();
requires on >= 0;
modifies ol.rep;
{
    assert ol in ol.rep;
    var n := on;
    var l : List? := ol;
    //    
    //
    while(n >= 0 && l != null) 
    invariant ol.valid();
    invariant (l != null) ==> l.valid();
    invariant (l != null) ==> (l in ol.rep);
    modifies l.rep;
    {
        l.data := n;
        l := l.next;
        n := n - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```
class List {
  var data : int;
  var next : List?;
  ghost var rep : set<List>;

  constructor(d : int) 
    ensures valid()
  {
    data := d;
    next := null;
    rep := {this};
  }

  predicate valid() 
    reads this, rep
    decreases rep + {this}
  {
    && this in rep
    && (next != null ==> 
        && next in rep
        && next.rep <= rep
        && this !in next.rep 
        && next.valid())
  }

  static twostate lemma valid_frame(a: List)
    requires old(a.valid())
    requires forall x | x in old(a.rep) :: unchanged(x`next)
    requires forall x | x in old(a.rep) :: unchanged(x`rep)
    decreases old(a.rep)
    ensures a.valid()
  {}
} 

method fill(ol : List, on : int) 
  requires ol.valid()
  requires on >= 0
  modifies ol.rep
  ensures ol.valid()
{
  var n := on;
  var l : List? := ol;
  label L:
  while(n >= 0 && l != null) 
    invariant l != null ==> l.valid()
    invariant l != null ==> l.rep <= old(ol.rep)
    modifies ol.rep`data
  {
    l.data := n;
    l := l.next;
    n := n - 1;
  }
  List.valid_frame@L(ol);
}
```

The basic idea of this proof is that the `valid` predicate only depends on the `next` and `rep` fields of `List`. Since `fill` only writes to the `data` field, it must preserve validity.

To implement the idea, we can use a `twostate` lemma in Dafny. The way to "pass" a particular old state to such a lemma uses a combination of the `label` feature and `@`.

Comment: Thanks James.  This is more involved than I was expecting.  It seems like it should be a simple thing to verify.  Also the `@L` notation didn't work on my version of Dafny under VSCode (3.0.0).